# R global date issue: all dates are converted to 1975

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I've encountered a strange issue in R recently:

I have noticed two related errors that I believe have to do with a global date setting in R, but I don't know what the issue is. First, when I use lubridate's "year" function, I get an origin error:

```
    library(lubridate)
    library(tidyverse)

    year(2008)
```

Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied

When I check origin

```
    lubridate::origin
```

It says:
[1] "1970-01-01 UTC"

Which is what I was under the impression it is supposed to say. When I try to use as.Date, it says that everything is the year 1975:

```
    as.Date(2008)
```

[1] "1975-07-02"

```
    as.Date(1910)
```

[1] "1975-03-26"

However, if I use

```
    ymd("2008-01-01") #it works fine:
```

[1] "2008-01-01"

I'm at a loss as to what to do - any advice? Thanks!

Comment: It is not a date object as it requires month and day

Comment: as a clue, what happens when you try `as.Date(0)` and `as.Date(1)`? How does `as.Date` know that you meant years? It thinks you meant days. Maybe try `as.Date(13879, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Answer (score 1):

Well, using `as.Date(2008)` you pass not a string, but a number. Therefore it takes 2008 days from `1970-01-01`, which is... `1975-07-02`! :-) Check that with:

```
as.Date("1970-01-01") + 2008
#> [1] "1975-07-02"
```

Similarly `1975-03-26` is 1910 days after the origin, `1970-01-01`:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("1975-03-26"))
#> [1] 1910
```

Note that passing only a year as a string takes today's day and month:

```
as.Date("2008", format = "%Y")
#> [1] "2008-07-14"
```

As for `lubridate`, function [`year()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/year.html) is for extracting a year from a date object, not to create a date from a string:

```
year(as.Date("1970-01-01"))
#> [1] 1970
```

If you want to convert a year as a string to a date, use e.g. [`parse_date_time()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_date_time.html):

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time("2008", orders = "%Y")
#> [1] "2008-01-01 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That totally makes sense